# React - rendering information in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a tip calculator. I need to render the result of the formula calculation in the div element. It works if insert formula directly into div, but I believe I have to use useState in this case. Here is the code I use. Could you please suggest how to fix it? thanks.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Calculation.css';
import Card from './UI/Card';

const Calculation = (props) => {

    const [tipPP, setTipPP]=useState('0');
    const [totalPP, setTotalPP] = useState('0');
        
        const calcHandler =()=>{
            
            setTipPP(((props.bill * props.tip) / props.people)/100);
            setTotalPP(props.bill/props.people + tipPP)

        }
        

    return (
        <Card className='calcCard' onChange = {calcHandler}>
            <div className='calcTip' >Tip amount<span className='tipTotal' >${tipPP}</span></div>
            <div className='calcTotal'>Total<span>${totalPP}</span></div>
            <Card className='resetBtn'>Reset</Card>
        </Card>
    )
};

export default Calculation;
```

Comment: Show code for `Card` component

Comment: How would you invoke the `clickHandler`

Answer (score -1):

How about :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './Calculation.css';
import Card from './UI/Card';

const Calculation = (props) => {

    const [tipPP, setTipPP]=useState('0');
    const [totalPP, setTotalPP] = useState('0');
        
        const calcHandler =(e)=>{
            e.preventDefault();
            setTipPP(((props.bill * props.tip) / props.people)/100);
            setTotalPP(props.bill/props.people + tipPP)

        }
        
     useEffect(() => {
         console.log("tipPP changed!");
     }, [tipPP]);

    return (
        <Card className='calcCard' onChange = {(e) => calcHandler()}>
            <div className='calcTip' >Tip amount<span className='tipTotal' >${tipPP}</span></div>
            <div className='calcTotal'>Total<span>${totalPP}</span></div>
            <Card className='resetBtn'>Reset</Card>
        </Card>
    )
};

export default Calculation;
```

useEffect will re-render the component when the value of tipPP changes.
Please try this.

Comment: thanks. it does  console.log but it does not solve the problem. it does not render tippPP and totalPP. Also, I am not sure if I use onChange here correctly. I don't think calcHandler function is executed.

Comment: @Alexey I have edited the answer can you please try it one more time.
the way to call calcHandler() is changed now.